# JavaFX action handler for MenuItem does nothing (FXML)

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml

Here is my Menu.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="biblereader.control.MenuController">
    <MenuBar fx:id="menu">
        <menus>
            <Menu text="File" fx:id="fileMenu">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem text="Open..." fx:id="open" onAction="#handleOpenAction" />
                    <MenuItem text="Exit"    fx:id="exit" onAction="#handleExitAction" />
                </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu text="Results" fx:id="resultsMenu">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem text="Save All Results" />
                    <MenuItem text="Load Results" />
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar> 
</StackPane>
```

And here is my MenuController.java:

```
package biblereader.control;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author nathan
 */
public class MenuController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private MenuBar menu;
    @FXML private Menu test;
    @FXML private MenuItem open;
    @FXML private MenuItem exit;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleExitAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("exiting");
        System.exit(0);
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleOpenAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("open bible");
    }
}
```

I've tried several different methods to make the action events actually trigger, but nothing I've done (through FXML) has actually accomplished the action event triggering.

The menu displays fine, but nothing happens on menu item clicks.

And yes, I have tried doing the following as well, in the controller:

```
exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
    exit.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    System.exit(0);
});
```

Still, nothing I have tried has worked. Any help I could get on this would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay, out of curiosity I wasted my time and created an application out of your code. The result: It all works, the events are firing. So the problem is somewhere in the code you are not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

As Roland pointed out, there was an error elsewhere which came from some refactoring issues.